# anaconda environment and ipykernel installation sequence

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to gain familiarity with using environments involving Anaconda and Jupyter. So far it hasn't been as easy as just using traditional Python environments, whether `pipenv`, `virtualenv`, or what-have-you. Below is a bash script illustrating the sequence of commands in order to make an *isolated* conda environment.

```
NAME=$1
conda create -n $NAME;
python -m ipykernel install --user --name $NAME --display-name "Python ($NAME)";
conda install -n $NAME ipykernel;
```

If I try to `conda install` the `ipykernel` before running the `python -m ipykernel install` command, then I am able to import packages that are globally installed via Anaconda (`numpy`, `pandas`, etc.); thus, I don't have the desired isolated environment. So, first, I don't understand why this is so difficult to match up conda environments with ipykernels. Second, why does this sequence work and not the other way around? Lastly, I don't really understand why both of these installation commands are required.

Also, I've tried using both installation commands alone, and I still don't achieve the desired result.

EDIT: Though this solution seemed to work at the time of posting, it no longer creates an isolated environment no matter the order of commands.

Comment: I don't understand how the conda install first doesn't work. What you have here is the `python` is run from the base environment because when you create an environment with no dependencies, no dependencies (including python) are added to the environment.

Comment: I am now confused as well. I just ran this sequence and it's still reaching for global packages, even though this seemed to be working last night.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities.

1 - The Conda path might not be there in environment path variables.

2 - This is a suggestion. Try using the Python itself over the Conda Environment. This saves a lot of memory and works best for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your first point? I can see anaconda in my PATH. When I make a new environment, it is also prepended to my path.

Comment: There is System Variable where you want to put your path. Doing this can help you access you conda env in all variables. You can find your environment variable in This PC Properties.